How do I present a measure based on parameters on different page?
I am working on a report in Power BI. I have defined some model parameters on page 1. With these parameters I created some calculated measures, for example:
inc =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( table1 ),
    FILTER (
        table1,
        table1[tr1] >= par1[ tr1 Value ]
            && table1[tr2] >= par2[ tr2 Value ]
    )
)

I present the results of this measure (1 or nothing) on another page. However, now when I change the values in the parameters, my results on page2 do not change with that.
I have tried the option of 'Sync slicers' in the view tab, but then it removes all results that do not correspond. I still want to keep all my rows, even though they do not match the criteria set by my measure based on those parameters.
How can I fix this?
